# How to share Shoutcast metadata over Lan?

Tags: javascript, html, metadata, shoutcast

We have a PC which we use to go to the Shoutcast home page and play some radio.

What happens often is that someone is courious about what song is being played, so someone (else) have to go to that PC and read aloud the artist / title.

I wonder if there's a way to put up something (an html page maybe?) so each one can look with his browser at the metadata .... and maybe have a popup notification (like Whatsapp web, to say something similar).

As a Windows programmer, i'm more used to think at executables and apps, i don't know much about server/client or HTML5/scripts capabilities so i wonder if there's a "simpler" solution than developing a brand new player just fo this purpose :)

Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify... you're listening to streams in-browser, correct?  And, you want to know how to make pop-ups in the notification area from browser?  Or open a browser somewhere else in the house to see what's playing on the other?

Comment: 1)Correct.   3)Correct   2)The pop-up could be a nice addition in the "browser somewhere else in the house" in your 3rd question.

Comment: Why not play your SHOUTcast streams in VLC and use something like Last.fm?

Comment: @Brad: i dont know much about these stuffs... isn't Last.Fm another radio? Sorry, I don't get what's your suggestion means... we only have that one PC with speakers on the office... it's an old PC devoted to some trivial task (like BigAnt server, autobackup of some LAN shared folder, and the web radio). That's why all I'd like is to know what song is playing from ShoutCast without having to get up and go there and look at the screen (and VNCs seems a bit too much for this).